# Expenses Tracker Django Web App: Issue with Extract all expenses, sort and aggregate total expenses by month to display as js with chart.js

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I am building a expenses tracker web app with django and have issues with the logic to sort and aggregate total expenses by month. The values are derived from a web form where the user enters an expense details which includes its date. From the date field, i want to sort and sum up each months total expenses to output the results as js into bar charts with chart.js. Should i be using                                     .annotate(month=ExtractMonth('date'))?

Under models.py:

```
class Expenses(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=266)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        ordering: ['-date']
```

Under views.py:

```
def db_expense_summary(request):                   #extract all expenses for past 6 months
    date_today = datetime.date.today()
    date_previous_six_months = date_today - datetime.timedelta(days=30*6)
    expenses =   Expenses.objects.filter(owner=request.user,date__gte=date_previous_six_months,date__lte=date_today)
    exp_total = {}                        #dictionary to store each month's expenses

    def get_month(expense):                #extract month values from expenses
        return expense.date.month 
 
    month_list = list(set(map(get_month, expenses))) 


    def get_expense_month_total(month):   # aggregate expenses amount by month   
        expense_amount=0                 
   
        filtered_by_month = expenses.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('date'))

        for item in filtered_by_month:
            expense_amount += item.amount
        return expense_amount   


for expense in expenses:    
    for month in month_list:
        exp_total[month] = get_expense_month_total(month)             
    
return JsonResponse({'expense_month_data': exp_total}, safe=False)
```

The results i got is:

```
{"expense_month_data": {"3": 12450.0, "4": 12450.0, "5": 12450.0}}
```

The individual months show up in the dictionary (3 - March, 4-April, 5- May) but the code logic is adding up all the expenses and not differentiating by month

The correct results i expect is:

```
{"expense_month_data": {"3": 100.0, "4": 12250.0, "5": 100.0}}
```